# My website source opencart is hacker How can fix?

Tags: opencart

my website: http://giakesieuthi.com.vn/

[image]

Can you help me fix it?

Comment: looks like its not hacked but the directory where you are trying to write images needs a writing permissions

Answer (score 0):

set the destination path to 777 permission for user www-data

```
chmod -R 777 /home/giake/domains/giakesieuthi.com.vn/public_html/image/cache/data
```

now check whether www-data can write data to that directory

When you website is on production, suppress the warnings, errors, parse errors, notices by using

```
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
```

or

```
//modify below error according to your needs
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
```